# how to write this sql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a rather simple question. How would I write this statement in php?

```
$q="SELECT t1.gebruikersnaam FROM tbel_leden as t1,instellingen as t2 WHERE
    t2.ledenid=t1.ledenid AND t2.livetracking=1";
```

I know it's just supposed to be a string but the error says unexpected t_variable and php admin is not helping either.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's the error line?  Sometimes when something goes wrong, the line indicated isn't always the culprit.  Try showing +2 lines in both directions.

Comment: Yes, I am very sure, I commented everything else out

Comment: thanks, you and Quassnoi where right on the money. 
I had a space between my php tag.<? php instead off <?php.

Answer (score 3):

Missed a dollar sign to denote a `php` variable:

```
$q="SELECT t1.gebruikersnaam FROM tbel_leden as t1,instellingen as t2 WHERE t2.ledenid=t1.ledenid AND t2.livetracking=1";
```

Comment: Ok, that was too easy, haha. Sorry I missed that, but that wasn't it

Comment: Unexpected t_varable is a PHP error, not MySQL. Check youк PHP code: you must have missed a brace or a parenthesis or something.

Answer (score 0):

$q="SELECT t1.gebruikersnaam 
FROM tbel_leden as t1
Left join instellingen as t2 on t2.ledenid=t1.ledenid 
WHERE t2.livetracking=1";

or

$q="SELECT t1.gebruikersnaam 
FROM tbel_leden as t1
join instellingen as t2 on t2.ledenid=t1.ledenid 
WHERE t2.livetracking=1";

it depends on what you want to get from DB. It's recommended to read a SQL spec about JOIN.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con){
  die('We don't have a connection: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("yourDB", $con);


$q = "SELECT t1.gebruikersnaam FROM tbel_leden as t1 Left join instellingen as t2 on       t2.ledenid=t1.ledenid WHERE t2.livetracking=1"; 
$result = mysql_query($q); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM)){ 
echo $row[0]."<br />"; 
} 


?>
```

you should try this code snippet.

Comment: I get what I want with my first select from within phpadmin, but not from the phpscript?

Comment: <?php

$q = "SELECT t1.gebruikersnaam FROM tbel_leden as t1 Left join instellingen as t2 on t2.ledenid=t1.ledenid WHERE t2.livetracking=1";
$result = mysql_query($q);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM)){
      echo $row[0]."<br />";
    }


?>


try this one.

Comment: of course you need first to make a db connection. before you do the select.